# How to select/remove the text blocks to first div? and if the text blocks overflow it will go to the 2nd div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

[image: Image 1]

[image: image 2]

I just want to select the text blocks into the underline and if the current text blocks is going to exceed the underline it will go to the 2nd underline. The 2 underline is 2 div that have different i.d The text blocks is in array.

How will I do it by using JavaScript or jQuery? Select and remove of the text blocks. And if the text blocks going to overflow from the first div it can go to the second div.

Comment: We need your code to help you ;)

Comment: `I just want to know how will i do it?` Check if `div` content is overflowing. If ya, prepend content element(s) while still overflowing to next `div`...

Comment: You might have an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What exactly areyou attempting to achieve by putting overflow content in a separate element?